# I can see answers from Deposit?

Tags: discussion

In the last days (and right now, too) I was able to see answers which got merged into my dear friend [Deposit](https://superuser.com/users/43131/deposit). Is that intentional? I always thought they would be hidden instantly?

Comment: If you spot any I missed, just flag them and I'll make them disappear

Comment: Oh and you might want to have a look at our chat next time you spot a spammer, but want a second opinion ;-)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Will do that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not hidden instantly. Deposit for all intent and purposes is a **normal user** just suspended for an extended period. Therefore anything we merge with Deposit we still need to manually delete. It's one of the reason I destroy accounts the first time, and only if the same account continues to pop up do I merge them with Deposit.